# Logarithm of complex matrix

Tags: matrices, logarithms, lie-groups, determinant

For invertible matrix $A$, we have

$\log(\det A) = \mathrm{tr}(\log A)$

due to a [corollary of Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#A_Lie_group_theory_perspective). What if we had the argument $iA$ instead? Would the above relation still hold?

Edit:

RHS $= \mathrm{tr}(\log(iA)) = \mathrm{tr}(i \tfrac{\pi}{2}+\log A) = i \tfrac{\pi}{2} + \mathrm{tr}(\log A) = i \tfrac{\pi}{2} + \log(\det A)$

Comment: $\log c A =  \log c + \log A$ and $\det (c A ) = c \det A$ so yes ? and the $\log$ of matrices works as the normal logarithm for sets of (inversible) matrices which commute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{tr}(\log (iA )) = \mathrm{tr}(i \pi/2 + \log A ) = i n \pi/2  + \mathrm{tr}(\log A )$$
When you multiply a matrix by a constant $c$, the determinant gets a factor of $c^n$.
$$\log(\det ( i A )) = \log( i^n \det A ) = \log( i^n  ) + \log( \det A ) = \log( i^n  ) +  \mathrm{tr}\log( A )$$

So in your case for the RHS to equal the LHS you want

$$\log(i^n) = i n\pi/2$$

But
$$\log(i^n) = \{ 0, i \pi/2, i\pi, i 3 \pi/2   \}$$
for $n$ modulo 4.

This is only going to work for you if $n < 4$. Otherwise it is false.

EDIT: In a sense it is true if you are going to treat the output as an angle for some complex number. In other words your equality is still true modulo $2 \pi$.

Comment: @ amcalde . Assume that we consider the principal $\log$ and that $A,iA$ have no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues. Then, in general, $\log(iA)\not=  i\pi/2.I_n+\log(A)$. For example choose $A=diag(e^{3i\pi/4},1)$; then $\log(A)=diag(3i\pi/4,0)$ and $\log(iA)=diag(-3i\pi/4,i\pi/2)$.